# telerik grid <-> nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have started to use telerik grids recently (for ASP.NET MVC). The 'Linq-based expression engine' does all the heavy lifting for you: paging, sorting and filtering. It just needs to be hooked up with a repository method like this:

public IEnumerable GetBlas()
{
    return Session.Query();
}

I have the following problem now. I would like to use ICriteria and Restrictions.In("x", list.ToArray()) where list is of type IList and is populated by another process. The problem is that list can contain hundreds of values and this might throw an exception as the generated SQL code’s ‘IN PART’ (e.g. IN (1, 2, ....., 10000)) might be far too long.

Is there a way to implement this without having to switch to pure SQL and dealing with all the query strings etc. the telerik grid sends? Hope this makes sense.

Thanks.

Christian

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is; you're afraid your 'in' clause would contain too many values? in that case, you can just split it into chucks, i.e `Restrinctions.In("x", sublist1) Or Restrictions.In("x",sublist2) etc.

Comment: This would still result in SQL code (generated by nhibernate) that is too long I believe! However I am not sure whether SQL server does not like the length of the sql or the number of parameters ...

Comment: not sure about sql server; this worked for me on Oracle. I suggest you give it a try and see how it goes.

Comment: could you please provide some (repository) code as answer. I just realised that (I think) the telerik 'Linq-based expression engine'  does not work with criteria ... not sure how to implement Restrictions.In with IQuery.

Comment: @csetzkom - how are you managing your NH sessions?  I've experienced performance problems with my app that keeps a session open to populate a DevExpress grid, which I'm currently trying to resolve.

Comment: I am using the sharp architecture which uses session per web request I believe.

Comment: Right - I see now that you're doing ASP.Net. Session per request should be OK.  I'm doing winforms, which seems to be more difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to divide the list of 10,000 items into smaller lists of (say) 1000 items each.
The easiest way to do the query is using `ICriteria`, where you can add as many `Disjunction`s as you need for each sub-collection you have.

If `ICriteria` is not an option, there can be a workaround where you create multiple `Future` queries, like so (tested code, which does only 1 roundtrip to the db):

```
string [] names = {"boris", "admin", "scheduleuser"}, moreNames = {"adminuser"};
var x = session.Query<User>()
                .Where(u => names.Contains(u.Name)).ToFuture();

var y = session.Query<User>()
                .Where(u => moreNames.Contains(u.Name)).ToFuture();

var res = x.Union(y);

log.DebugFormat("found {0} users. 1st user is : {1}", res.Count(), res.Count() > 0 ? res.First().FullName : "none");
```

Comment: wow that looks great. just need to think about the dynamic situation where I do not know how many x and y-s there are ...

Comment: you'll need a `List<IQueryable>` to replace `x` and `y` in the example, and then iterate over it, `Union`ing the whole thing. nothing to it, really :)